# fusermount permission denied

Tags: sshfs

I have used sshfs on my Linux Mint machine to mount a directory from a different machine in the internet. This worked out of the box.

Then I tried the exact same command on a Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) and got this error:

```
~$ sshfs -v <some machine on the interwebs> ~/fusessh/
fusermount3: mount failed: Permission denied
```

These are the permissions in my home directory on the Ubuntu machine:

```
drwx------ 27 my_user group_a    4096 Sep 15 14:36 .
drwx------  2 my_user group_b  4096 Aug 23 13:06 Desktop
drwx------  2 my_user group_b  4096 Aug 23 13:06 Documents
drwx------  2 my_user group_b  4096 Aug 23 13:06 Downloads
drwx------  2 my_user group_b  4096 Sep 12 14:04 fusessh
```

my_user is in both group_a and group_b.

```
~$ groups thsi
my_user : group_b sudo group_a
```

Edit based on the comments:

```
~$ ls -l /bin/fusermount3
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35200 Mar 23  2022 /bin/fusermount3
```

In sandbox mode:

```
~$ unshare --map-root-user
~# ls -l /bin/fusermount3 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 35200 Mar 23  2022 /bin/fusermount3
```

Comment: It's likely because mounting VFS requires `sudo`, but you could create a userspace mapping your user to `root` with `unshare --map-root` then try your `sshfs ...` command again from the new userspace and see if it works.

Comment: The point of fuse is to work in user mode (afaik), and I need a solution that does not require sudo (I am in the sudo group but I want this to work for non-sudo users).

Comment: You should run `unshare --map-root-user` **without** `sudo` ... That is called user namespace/sandboxing  and it's even safer than using your own user in the plain especially with Internet mounts ... Please see [How do I use the user namespace sandbox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1475711)

Comment: Doing this resulted in `fusermount3: mount failed: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Could you please show the output of `ls -l /bin/fusermount3`

Comment: Sure, it returns this: `-rwsr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 35200 Mar 23  2022 /bin/fusermount3`

Comment: Are you doing `ls -l /bin/fusermount3` from within a user namespace/sandbox or under your normal user ... If the former, then please open a new terminal and run the command again and show the output ... If the latter, then the ownership is not correct and you need to correct it with `sudo chown root:root /bin/fusermount3` then run `sudo chmod u+s /bin/fusermount3`

Comment: I edited the post. I am not sure if the behavior is normal. In user mode, the ownership seems correct. With the sandbox, it seems off

Comment: It's correct under your user and the other output is also normal in the sandbox ... So, that's not the problem. and I'm out of ideas as to why you get `fusermount3: mount failed: Permission denied` except for the lack of group and especially others permissions on the mount point ... So, try  `chmod 0775 ~/fusessh/` and see if that works.

Comment: It is strange, I did chmod as you put just now  and it works.

Comment: I tested a bit more, and it seems the execute permissions are the essential thing. But now I am unable to unmount. It says Permission denied and when I do it with the GUI a small note pops up saying some data needs to be written before the device can be unmounted.

Comment: That might mean the write permission is also needed for others so try `chmod 0777 ~/fusessh/` on the mount point while the filesystem is unmounted although I can't see how that would apply the mount itself ... If that didn't work, then you might want to mount the filesystem and check the permission while mounted.

Comment: I have tried with 777 permissions, but still permission denied when I try to unmount.
The permissions seem to be the same before mounting and when I mounted the remote folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run `id` to double check the user and group IDs of your accounts on both your local and remote systems. I'm guessing they're different, even if the names are the same. In that case FUSE is trying to modify the local mount point as an `other` user, as far as `chmod` and permissions are concerned. Therefore, you need to `chmod o+rx ~/fusessh`. The mode (permissions) of this mount point will be modified by the mode of the root of the filesystem that you mount, otherwise the directory should be empty if nothing is mounted, so giving `other` read and execute permissions shouldn't be much of a security risk.

In order to unmount, *every directory* in the mount path needs to have execute permissions. Run `realpath ~/fusessh`, then make sure that each directory in that path has the execute bit set for `other` (still assuming that UID/GID are different on each system).

*Note: I post this now because I encountered these exact same issues today. To be honest, I don't know exactly how FUSE works under the hood. In my case the UID was the same on both systems, but the GID differed. Still, nothing worked until I gave permissions to `other`. I experimented with the `uid`, `gid`, and `default_permissions` mount options, but none of those fixed the issues. It seems to me that those mount options only changed their respective attributes **after** the filesystem was mounted, but that FUSE was operating under the UID/GID of the remote system **before** the mount finalized. Again, this is only speculation, but it fits the behavior.*