# Can’t run any flatpak app

Tags: flatpak, 23.10

Every flatpak app fails with this message:

```
$ flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox 
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
error: ldconfig failed, exit status 256
```

Ubuntu Mantic, flatpak installed with apt.

It must be something with bubblewrap or with the way it’s used, because:

```
$ bwrap 
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
$ sudo bwrap 
usage: bwrap [OPTIONS...] [--] COMMAND [ARGS...]

    --help                       Print this help
    --version                    Print version
    ...
```

More info for commenters:

```
$ type -a bwrap 
bwrap is /bin/bwrap
bwrap is /usr/bin/bwrap
bwrap is /bin/bwrap
$ ls -l /usr/bin/bwrap /bin/bwrap 
.rwxr-xr-x 72k root 28 Feb 10:38 /usr/bin/bwrap
.rwxr-xr-x 72k root 28 Feb 10:38 /bin/bwrap
$ sudo flatpak repair
[21/23] Verifying flathub:app/com.google.Chrome/x86_64/stable…
Checking remotes...
Pruning objects
Erasing .removed

$ unshare --map-root-user 
$ whoami
root
$ sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone
kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1
```

I tried to set setuid for bwrap:

```
$ sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/bwrap
```

That makes flatpaks run, but with an ugly warning. I don’t think that’s a correct solution.

[image]

Comment: Please add to your question how Flatpak is installed and which release of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: Please add the output of `type -a bwrap` and `ls -l /usr/bin/bwrap /bin/bwrap`

Comment: Also, please run `sudo flatpak repair` and add it's output to your question as well.

Comment: You should not need setuid, so remove it `sudo chmod -s /usr/bin/bwrap` … But you need the owner to be root, so change it `sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/bwrap`

Comment: User namespaces are enabled by default on recent kernels, so you shouldn’t need to do any of the other instructions printed in your terminal screenshot either.

Comment: `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/bwrap` is another way of removing setuid bit as well if you prefer it.

Comment: By the way ... You are running the default Ubuntu kernel, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I did 0755. Yes, default kernel.

Comment: setuid might be needed only if the kernel user namespaces is disabled ... See https://askubuntu.com/a/1475718 and check please.

Comment: That works fine, see edit.

Comment: That leaves flatpak itself as a potential culprit ... Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure flatpak` and check ... If not fixed, try `sudo apt install --reinstall flatpak` ... If not, then be prepared to uninstall all flatpak apps with `flatpak uninstall --all` then purge the package manager itself with `sudo apt purge flatpak` ... Then, install it again `sudo apt install flatpak` ... **SAVE YOUR DATA FIRST** that might be handled by or saved under currently installed flatpak applications **BEFORE PURGING FLATPAK**

Comment: Don't remove Bubblewrap ... Sorry, Many reverse dependencies, so not a good idea .. But a reinstall should be safe `sudo apt install --reinstall bubblewrap`

Comment: I tried all of that.

Comment: It's obvious what is happening, but not why it's happening ... Therefore, I added some notes that hopefully will help ... As a side note for encouragement, I think it's solvable and rather simple to do so, but I can't recommend thing like e.g. purging Bubblewrap then reinstalling it as it has many reverse dependencies and requires a certain level of care (*the at your own risk kind*) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but important notes that don't fit into comments and will most likely help you or others trying to help solve this issue.

#### Note #1

This:

```
$ bwrap 
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
```

Can be reproduced (*on other systems with default normal functioning `bwrap` command*) when nesting containers within other containers and asking for all capabilities to be used with e.g. `--cap-add ALL` like for example:

```
$ bwrap --bind / / --cap-add ALL -- bwrap --bind / / -- bash
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
```

... Bubblewrap drops all capabilities within a sandbox and the child tasks cannot gain greater privileges than their parent. That's how it works, but I can't go into detail about how that might be causing this.

Now, why this is happening depends on what you have done either deliberately by hand or unknowingly by some script/package you installed ... So, only you can guess what.

Probable causes might be that you have enabled persistent user namespaces/sandboxes or something like it related to Bublewrap configuration/settings.

#### Note #2

```
$ type -a bwrap 
bwrap is /bin/bwrap
bwrap is /usr/bin/bwrap
bwrap is /bin/bwrap
```

... should print `bwrap is /bin/bwrap` only once unless there are two routs leading to it ... Find out why and fix it.

#### Note #3

The [kernel feature](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475718/968501) allowing unprivileged users namespaces is enabled by default in recent Ubuntu kernels ... That is a requirement for Bubblewrap to work without the setuid bit (*the default*) or otherwise the setuid bit on the executable binary file i.e. `/usr/bin/bwrap` might be required.

#### Note #4

The default ownership and permissions on the executable `/usr/bin/bwrap` should be:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/bwrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72160 Feb 25  2022 /usr/bin/bwrap
```

... those can be restored with first setting ownership:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/bwrap
```

... then setting permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/bwrap
```

or both actions at once with:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 0755 /usr/bin/bwrap
```

Comment: It's weird having two /bin/bwrap files, how is that possible? Is one a link?

Comment: @pbhj Given how `type` works and that the `-a` option searches every entry/directory in the user's search PATH, it could be as benign as a repeated `/bin` entry e.g. do `PATH="${PATH}:/bin"` and then do `type -a bwrap` to see how that is reflected in the output, but this case isn't common or expected (*indicating some tinkering done by the user*) and also it could be something else as well so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: That’s the case. I’ve got `export PATH="$CARGO_HOME/bin:$PATH"` while $CARGO_HOME being undeclared.